# Tooltip not appearing when clicking on the input field

Tags: html, css

So I only want the tooltip to show when I click on the input field, but unfortunately, it doesn't appear at all...
Here is my CSS / HTML:

```css
.tooltip {
    color: rgb(143, 143, 143);
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: Arial;
    padding-left: 24px;
    padding-right: 24px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 60px;
    background-color: black;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    border-radius: 5px;
    bottom: -86px;
}

.search_twitter:focus .tooltip {
    visibility: visible;
}
```

```html
<div class="t_header_right"> 
  <input type="text" placeholder="Search Twitter" class="search_twitter">
  <img src="thumbnails/svgexport-29.svg" class="search_icon">
  <div class="tooltip">
    Try searching for people, topics, or keywords
  </div>
</div>
```

EDIT: So I realized it's most likely because the input box is not a parent of the tooltip, therefore, it can't use the CSS. Well, how do I make the input field a parent?

Comment: You don’t need to change your markup at all, contrary to the accepted answer. Just use a general sibling selector: `.search_twitter:focus ~ .tooltip`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`.tooltip` isn't a child of `.search_twitter`, so your `.search_twitter:focus .tooltip` selector doesn't hit.

You could move it to be the next sibling of the input and update the selector to use an [adjacent sibling selector](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Adjacent_sibling_combinator): `search_twitter:focus + .tooltip`.

```css
.tooltip {
    color: rgb(143, 143, 143);
    font-size: 14px;
    font-family: Arial;
    padding-left: 24px;
    padding-right: 24px;
    padding-top: 15px;
    padding-bottom: 60px;
    background-color: black;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.5);
    position: absolute;
    visibility: hidden;
    border-radius: 5px;
    bottom: -86px;
}

.search_twitter:focus + .tooltip {
    visibility: visible;
}

.t_header_right {
  position: relative; /* for tooltip positioning context */
}
```

```html
<div class="t_header_right"> 
  <input type="text" placeholder="Search Twitter" class="search_twitter">
  <div class="tooltip">
    Try searching for people, topics, or keywords
  </div>
  <img src="thumbnails/svgexport-29.svg" class="search_icon">
</div>
```

Comment: Thanks a lot man, the adjacent sibling selector has done it for me!